# Is web indexed db data permanently preserved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, web, indexeddb

Cookies, local storage disappears when users delete site data, but I wonder if indexed db is not deleted.

Or is there any other storage that can't be deleted?

Thank you.

Comment: Everything can be destroyed, if you need permanent data storage, use your server.

Comment: IndexdDB is subject to [eviction policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria)